# PHP loop for all child of parent and child of childs

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Good day guys! I have a problem with my code, this code's function is to display all child from one single parent from top to bottom. But the problem is I am stuck with the third level child. What I want is to get all the child without using repetitive coding just like what you guys are seeing below:

```
<div>
            <div>
                <?php
                echo $root; //Parent head
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            foreach ($row => $value){ //Set all values which has parent_id of $root to $value
                ?>
                <div style="float:<?php echo $value['position']; ?>;">
                    <?php echo $value['childusername']; ?> //Display Child

    <?php
                    $under2 = getchildofchild($value['codezone'],$value['root_id'],$value['childusername']);
                    foreach ($under2 as $row2 => $value2){?><br>
                        <div style="float:<?php echo $value2['position']; ?>;">
                            <?php echo $value2['childusername']; ?>

    <?php
                            $under3 = getchildofchildofchild($value2['codezone'],$value2['root_id'],$value2['username']);
                            foreach ($under3 as $row3 => $value3){?><br>
                                <div style="float:<?php echo $value3['position']; ?>;">
                                    <?php echo $value3['childusername']; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
```

Then I want it to look like a binary tree style view. My database looks like this:

```
+----+----------+
| id | sponsorID |
+----+----------+
|  1 |     NULL |
|  2 |        1 |
|  3 |        1 |
|  4 |        2 |
|  5 |        2 |
|  6 |        3 |
|  7 |        3 |
|  8 |        4 |
|  9 |        4 |
+----+----------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use recursion to solve this.

Comment: @sandeepsure I used recursion on my former code just a while ago, but in the end I resorted to this. The moment I used recursive code, the data that should be posted was displayed multiple via loop.